# Replace elements in an array whose indexes do not match the given indexes

Tags: ruby, arrays, indexing

I have the following two variables:

```
array = ['h','e','l','l','o']
string = '023'
```

All the elements in `array` that do not have indexes matching someplace in the `string` need to be replaced with underscores. The new array should look like this: `['h','_','l','l','_']`.

I was thinking of doing something like this

```
.map.with_index do |e,i|
  if (i != string) #Somehow get it to check the entire string
    e = '_'
  end
end
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Does `'023'` expand to `[0,2,3]` or `[0,23]`? The question would be improved it you changed that to an array of indices.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
array = ['h','e','l','l','o']
string = '023'
```

Surely, the first step is to convert `string` to an array of indices, the way they probably should be stored in the first place, in part to allow the use of indices greater than nine:

```
indices = string.each_char.map(&:to_i)
  #=> [0, 2, 3]
```

Once that is done, there are umpteen ways to do the replacements. Assuming `array` is not to be mutated, here's a very straightforward way:

```
indices.each_with_object([?_]*array.size) { |i,arr| arr[i] = array[i] }
  #=> ["h", "_", "l", "l", "_"]
```

If you prefer, these two lines could be combined:

```
string.each_char.map(&:to_i).each_with_object([?_]*array.size) do |i,arr|
  arr[i] = array[i]
end
```

Alternatively,

```
string.each_char.with_object([?_]*array.size) do |c,arr|
  i = c.to_i
  arr[i] = array[i]
end
```

Comment: I really liked `indices.each_with_object([?_]*array.size) { |i,arr| arr[i] = array[i] }` line. Kudos.

Answer (score 2):

Since you already know the positions to preserve, just use that as a pattern:

```
array = %w[ h e l l o ]
string = '023'

# Create a replacement array that's all underscores
replacement = [ '_' ] * array.length

# Transpose each of the positions that should be preserved
string.split(//).each do |index|
  index = index.to_i

  replacement[index] = array[index]
end

replacement
# => ["h", "_", "l", "l", "_"]
```

If your index specifier changes, you'll need to re-write that parser to convert accordingly. For example, if you need numbers over 9 you might switch to comma separated.

Comment: IMHO You should use `each_char` instead of `split(//).each`

Comment: I was thinking of using that, but this is more easily adapted to a comma-separated approach by switching to `/,/` instead.

Comment: @CarySwoveland Fixed. Thanks for noticing that.

Answer (score 1):

```
 array.map.with_index{|x,i|!string.include?(i.to_s)?'-':x}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution:

```
string = %w[ h e l l o ]
indexes = '023'

(
  0.upto(string.size - 1).to_a -
  indexes.each_char.map(&:to_i)
).each do |i|
  string[i]= '_'
end

puts string.inspect
# => ["h", "_", "l", "l", "_"]
```